# Why does reserved virtual memory grow while virtual memory currently in use doesn't grow?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, memory-leaks

My application gets bad_alloc exception. 
Resource Monitor shows that virtual memory reserved by OS (Commit) exceeded 2G.
However, virtual memory currently in use by the process (Working Set) is pretty small (at time of crash it can be around 200000 Kb).
How it can happen? I noticed that when program starts those two are almost of the same size (Commit is a little bit bigger). But with time passing difference grows and it seems to me because when the second memory (Working Set) increases, the fist one (Commit) increases too. But when the second one decreases, the first one doesn't go back.
I use three different computers and everywhere have this behaviour. I use Windows 7 and program is written in C++.

What could cause such a behaviour?
Thank you

Comment: You are allocating large arrays that you don't actually use to capacity.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes caused by the memory allocation pattern of your application. If, for example, you have data structures that are always growing, and defer some time the deletion of the previous buffers (those that run out of space), then you can observe this behavior with the heap. This is caused because maybe when your program tries to allocate a greater chunk of memory, it has no space *before* the actual buffer, so it has to grow the allocated heap to allocate the greater chunk. Maybe then afterwards you delete the old buffer, but the heap has increased already. Maybe even after, in another loop, you use pieces of the freed memory that again don't leave enough space for the next bigger block, and so on, so the memory is exhausted.

It would help to show a rough description of the inner workings of your program in terms of memory management.

Comment: The memory management is not simple and program is big. As usually in Memory Managers, I preallocate space and work with chanks of it. But what is really strange is fact that Commit becames 1000 times bigger than Private, let's say now I see 1370528 against 11920.

Comment: Then don't preallocate. Allocate just what you need *and when* you need. It is a better programming practice.

Comment: Of course ratio was 100 in my first comment. But usually when it got bad_alloc and Commit is equal 2020000 Kb. the Private is usually something like 200000 Kb

Comment: My program is time critical and memory management is very important part of speed increase.

Answer (score 0):

The "Working Set" is the amount of pages that is made visible by the OS to your application. The OS tries to reduce it all the time.

If you allocate memory and don't use it, the working set will be small. But the memory you allocate has to fit in the virtual adress space of your application anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't sure what those "Working Set" and "Commit" meant. From your answer I concluded it was definitely physical and virtual memory. So, it just encouraged me to look harder and I found culprit - when I looked for previous error I substituted "new" for memory allocations with help of memory manager (respectively "delete" for deallocations). But later, when error was found I didn't returned everything back. Thank you.

Comment: Ah so it was a leak after all. I suspected so. Please mark one of the answers as "the answer" (green checkmark on the left).